# C: Is an Anonymous Array Allocated on the Heap or Stack?

Tags: c, pointers, memory, anonymous

For example this code here:

```
char *s = "Hello";
```

Where is "Hello" being stored? Is it stored the same in memory just anonymously?

Comment: What is anonymous about that? I don't get it.

Comment: take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_segment

Comment: This one is allocated in the RO-data section of the executable image.

Comment: @Jefffrey I apologize if I'm wrong about it being anonymous. I'm a noob with C. I was going by [this page](http://www.c4learn.com/c-programming/difference-between-char-pointer-char-array/). I assume it's anonymous because "Hello" doesn't have a name. Only a pointer to its address.

Comment: The "hello" bit is in the read section of the program. S will be on the stack

Comment: @EdHeal: `s` will not be on the stack if it's a global variable.

Comment: @Jefffrey: The array is anonymous. `s` is not, but `s` is a pointer, not an array.

Comment: BTW: You might want to read about compound-literals as well.

Comment: Sorry if this was a duplicate. I guess I didn't try enough search queries. Thanks for the information and reading material though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

String literals have static storage duration and are allocated in the static memory that is neither on the stack nor in the heap. For example they can be allocated in a read only data segment.

Comment: I see no reason to downvote it. It's valid answer.

Comment: @Grzegorz Szpetkowski It could be discussed if the reason were known.

Answer (score 2):

C Standard does not define, where string literals are stored (it does not even use terms like stack nor heap). It only tells that it has static storage duration. Typically it means that it's located in <strike>heap</strike> the [data segment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_segment).

Comment: There is no reason to down-vote this answer! The C-language standard indeed doesn't define where variables should be allocated (as far as I know, not only string literals, but any other type of variables as well). It is generally subjected to compiler implementation. You could add the notion that in practice, most decent compilers allocate string literals in the RO-data section of the executable image. But somebody is most definitely playing around with the votes here.

Comment: @barakmanos: Grzegorz is correct that the standard doesn't say where string literals are stored. But they are not typically located on the heap. The heap is the region of memory managed by `malloc` and `free`. The stack, the heap, and the static data area are typically three distinct regions.

Comment: @KeithThompson: Oh yeah, I see that part of the answer now... I guess I read only the first sentence (BTW, this can be inferred from the part in my comment about string literals typically located in the RO-data section).